# Groovy script that converts positive integers to their Roman Numeral equivalent

Tags: groovy

I need to write a Groovy script that converts positive integers to their Roman Numeral equivalent. What code structure should be in the Logic part to be provided by me the switch statement?

Comment: def emitRNValue(int quotient, int divisor) {Map strokes = [1000:['M','?','?'],
100:['C','D','M'],
10:['X','L','C'],
1:['I','V','X']]
// Logic to be provided by me.
// switch statement missing.
}
def processNumber(int n) {
print "Number: ${n} "
int divisor = 1000
while (n > 0) {
// need integer division here
int quotient = n.intdiv(divisor)
emitRNValue(quotient,divisor)
//println "divisor: ${divisor} quotient ${quotient}"
// now make the number & divisor smaller
n = n - quotient * divisor
divisor = divisor.intdiv(10)
}
println()
}
processNumber(3569)
processNumber(1234)

Comment: If you have code, that works for you, please add an answer (it's OK to answer your own question and to upvote etc). And if this code in your comment, that fails, please add it to the question and also what fails.